# Anchoring checkbox in Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am creating a winform based Desktop application and I am using `Datagridview` to populate the data.

I am using `checkbox` in one of the header column. The Table is quiet big to fit into the screen and am using scroll bar to move in the horizontal and vertical direction.

The `checkbox` need to move as the scroll bar moves. However, the problem is it remains static.

Any idea how to anchor it, so that when the scroll bar moves, the checkbox moves accordingly.[image]

Thanks

EDIT :

Auto generated Designer Code :

```
            this.checkheader.AutoSize = true;
            this.checkheader.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.checkheader.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.checkheader.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(49, 96);
            this.checkheader.Name = "checkheader";
            this.checkheader.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
            this.checkheader.TabIndex = 21;
            this.checkheader.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.checkheader.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.checkboxHeader_CheckedChanged);
        //
```

Comment: how do you put check-box to header? is it just static control on top of grid?

Comment: How do you use the checkbox in one of the header column? Can you explain code?

Comment: could you please show us the auto generated designer code?

Comment: Wow, I did not even know you can have a CheckBox in the header. Definitely +1 for the question. :)

Comment: Looks the checkbox is not inside a column instead is just place over a column header therefore it would not move along with scrollbar. It need kind of overlay to show as if its part of header cell.

Comment: Along with what @Needo is saying, it's just drawn in front of the DataGridView control, which is why it doesn't move along with the scroll bar. What exactly do you need a checkbox within a datagridview for?

Comment: I am using the static checkbox as Select All option. One of the column in the Datagridview is a checkbox column. So, when the static checkbox is clicked(checked) it checks all the checkboxes in the column.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the datagridview 'scroll'-event to do something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ScrollOrientation.Equals(ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll))
        {
            checkBox1.Location = new Point(checkBox1.Location.X - (e.NewValue - e.OldValue), checkBox1.Location.Y);
        }
        if (checkBox1.Location.X < dataGridView1.Location.X + 40)
        {
            checkBox1.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Better late than never ?